# Is it a bad idea to monitor hardware and processes while playing a game or using a CPU intensive program?

Tags: cpu, process, gpu, temperature, window

For example, using something like Open Hardware Monitor to check CPU temperature, while running a game in another window. Neither are minimized.

Or using Process Explorer with a web browser open as another window. Neither are minimized.

Would this stress out the GPU and CPU?

Comment: What exactly is your concern about "stress"?  Power consumption?  Component life span?  Process hogging?

Comment: Component lifespan. Will it overwork the GPU and CPU to monitor them and display that constantly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will running those processes add additional stress to your system? Yes. Reason being that they are polling for the information they get. However, I seriously doubt that you should be concerned about that kind of overhead on any modern system. The machine is pretty good at scheduling tasks generally. In the case of a game, it is pretty unlikely that you'll have noticeable impact unless you're running a very low-end system.

Additionally, most of the monitoring applications allow you to choose polling speed if you're worried about that..

PS: By "stress", I simply mean more work for your computer to do. Whether you're computing FFTs or running MS Paint

Comment: Would running those monitoring applications most of the time be bad?

Comment: It will only be bad if you notice a performance drop when having them open. Else, don't worry too much about it :)

Answer (score 1):

Very unlikely to stress out anything to a noticeable extent. It's more stressful to dual screen the performance monitor while you game, as your GPU has to pump out twice as many pixels.
If you are single-screening it, the performance difference will not affect your game I imagine.

Comment: Well, Open Hardware Monitor and Process Explorer constantly interact with the hardware for temperature and CPU usage respectively. Would that put any more stress on the CPU and GPU than regular running or rendering?

Comment: It constantly interacts, but it barely uses any resources to grab those figures from their respective controllers. I would say < 0.1% performance decrease

Answer (score 1):

In fact the opposite is true, **you need to monitor your computer under load only then will weakness be exposed to the light of day**.  Any computer can run fine staring at the desktop all day.  However, if you want to check your other components they need to be under load.  You power supply might be fine at the desktop, but if components such as the CPU and GPU are maxed then are your voltages within 5% +/- of the correct voltage.  Same thing with the CPU, you won't know if your heatsink is sufficient unless you monitor it under 100% load.